# Creating dynamic facets using apache solr

Tags: apache, solr

I'm new to apache solr.

I have uploaded a few log files using solr-cell and I want to create facets based on the content which is there in the log file.

For example: inside my log file I have a record for transaction, I would like to create transactionid as my facet and clicking it should result in a search in the uploaded log files and give me results according to that particular id.

Note: I need to facet field according to the content which is in the log.

Comment: If I have understood this correctly, you basically don't know upfront, which field you want to facet on, is that right?

Comment: exactly as i upload a log file it should create dynamic facets based on the content in the log file (eg transactionid)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the field is indexed, you can facet on it. So, you can use either *schemaless* configuration or use dynamicField definitions to match and automatically create fields for your log records.

Go through Solr examples first, there should be enough information there.

(updated based on the comments)
If the text needs to be pre-processed and split, there are two basic avenues:

1. Using DataImportHandler (DIH), probably with [LineEntityProcessor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-LineEntityProcessor) and [RegexTransformer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-TheRegexTransformer) to split the field into multiple fields
2. Using UpdateRequestProcessor chains (in solrconfig.xml) and probably clone the field multiple times and then use [RegexReplaceProcessorFactory](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/#RegexReplaceProcessorFactory) to extract relevant parts. That's even uglier than DIH though as there is no easy way to split one field into many.

Still, specifically for logs, it is better to use something like [Logstash with Solr output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-solr_http.html).

Comment: my problem is if i have text file for suppose and the content in it is "2016-02-25 18:05:44,821 [WebContainer : 6] DEBUG [74311F40D97148, USER_ID: EXAMINER6] - com.apache.org.plm.usersearch.client.UserSearchAPI - { LOG PROPERTIES: ProcessTime: 0ms, COMPONENT_NAME: USERSEARCH, TransRefGUID: 7431C9280D97148, USER_ID: EXAMINER6, } Invoking proxy.............." and if i have indexed it then i need only Examiner as my facet or TransRefGUID as my facet .For such kind do we have any solution in solr

Comment: This looks like Logfile content. Which means it needs to be parsed and split into fields. You can do it with regular expressions in Solr, but that's not the best path. You should look into log parsing solutions, which usually feed into other products, including Solr. Or look into Elastic(search) stack which specializing in logfile processing, indexing and searching.

Comment: could you please let me know how can we do it through using regular expression..exactly where i need to make the changes?

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Alex's answer.

Another alternative is to write a custom update processor where you figure out what field you want to facet on and explicitly add that field to your document.
This makes sense only if you know what kind of fields to expect, based on some pattern. If that is not the case, then using dynamic fields or a schemaless config is your best bet.

Comment: I tried indexing content and added it as a facet but that created many irrelevant facets (even though it picked from content )which i don't even need it . could you clarify how to make it possible..as i have referred the docs but that dint help me

Comment: You'll have to identify patterns in your logs, that is if there are any to begin with. Once you do that, you can use regex to extract the relevant fields and index them.

Comment: could you please quote an example on how to use use regex to extract the relevant fields and index them.if suppose i  have identified  patterns?

Comment: Let's assume that you are looking to facet on all fields that begin with `transaction`. In such a case you would use a regex like the following:
`(^transaction.*)`. This is a very simple example and the actual regex may be much more complex depending on your use case.

Comment: You can use dynamicField definition with stored=false indexed=false to match those fields you do not want (as long as they have semi-consistent name patterns). They will make it to Solr and then be effectively discarded.

Comment: my problem is if i have text file for suppose and the content in it is "2016-02-25 18:05:44,821 [WebContainer : 6] DEBUG [74311F40D97148,  USER_ID: EXAMINER6] - com.apache.org.plm.usersearch.client.UserSearchAPI  - { LOG PROPERTIES:  ProcessTime: 0ms,  COMPONENT_NAME: USERSEARCH,  TransRefGUID: 7431C9280D97148,  USER_ID: EXAMINER6,  }  Invoking proxy.............."                         and if i have indexed it then i need only Examiner as my facet or TransRefGUID as my facet .For such kind do we have any solution in solr

Comment: No, I don't think so. Since you're extracting field names and values from text, dynamic fields won't work alone, a custom update processor is the way to go for this along with dynamic fields if you so desire.

Comment: any link or example for that ??

Comment: For now, google is your best bet. I do have a github repo where I've demonstrated use of solr plugins but as of now there's no example for an update processor. I am going to put up an example later this week, so [here's](https://github.com/lttazz99/SolrPluginsExamples) the link.